# R: how to get last sold out date for each buying?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

let say i'm a fruit vendor, and i have 2 table. 1 for buying and 1 for sales like bellow,

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)

FruitBought <- tribble(
~name, ~Date, ~Qty,
"Apple", 20180101, 15,
"Apple", 20180105, 20,
"Banana", 20180102, 18,
"Banana", 20180109, 14
)

fruitSold <- tribble(
  ~Date,    ~name,  ~sold,
  20180101, 'Apple',    5,
  20180102, 'Apple',    3,
  20180102, 'Banana',   3,
  20180103, 'Apple',    1,
  20180103, 'Banana',   4,
  20180104, 'Apple',    2,
  20180104, 'Banana',   2,
  20180105, 'Apple',    1,
  20180105, 'Banana',   2,
  20180106, 'Apple',    2,
  20180106, 'Banana',   3,
  20180107, 'Apple',    2,
  20180107, 'Banana',   1,
  20180108, 'Apple',    0,
  20180108, 'Banana',   3,
  20180109, 'Apple',    2,
  20180109, 'Banana',   1,
  20180110, 'Apple',    3,
  20180110, 'Banana',   1
)
```

I want to get last sold out date for each buying. like this.

```
name     | Date     | Qty | LastSoldOut
"Apple"  | 20180101 | 15  | 20180107
"Apple"  | 20180105 | 20  | NA
"Banana" | 20180102 | 18  | 20180109
"Banana" | 20180109 | 14  | NA
```

Is there anyone can help?

Comment: What is the logic of selecting the `LastSoldOut` date? For "Apple" you also have dates which are greater than "20180107"

Comment: you need to provide some unique identifier for each buying item , otherwise for system everything will be same

Comment: @RonakShah, ah, i mean,
on January 1st I bought 15 Apples, I want to know when that 15 apples sold out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Here is a possible approach using `data.table` non-equi join:

```
#calculate the available stock at each date
FruitBought[, CumAvail:=cumsum(Qty), by=.(name)]

#calculate the fruits sold up to date
cumsold <- fruitSold[, .(Date, SoldToDate=cumsum(sold)), .(name)]

#use non-equi join to find the first date where 
#sold to date is greater than available stock as per OP
cumsold[
    FruitBought, on=.(name=name, Date>=Date, SoldToDate>CumAvail),
    #for each row in FruitBought, find that first date
    .(Name=i.name, Date=i.Date, Qty, LastSoldOut=x.Date[1L]), by=.EACHI][,
        -(1L:3L)] #remove the joining columns
```

**2)** You can also use the `data.table`'s `roll` argument by slightly tweaking the number sold to date:

```
FruitBought[, CumAvail:=cumsum(Qty), by=.(name)]
cumsoldTweak <- fruitSold[, .(Date, SoldToDate=cumsum(sold)-1e-2), .(name)]    
cumsoldTweak[FruitBought, on=c("name", SoldToDate="CumAvail"), roll=-Inf,
    .(name, Date=i.Date, Qty, LastSoldOut=Date)]
```

output:

```
     Name     Date Qty LastSoldOut
1:  Apple 20180101  15    20180107
2:  Apple 20180105  20          NA
3: Banana 20180102  18    20180109
4: Banana 20180109  14          NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table) 
#data.table 1.11.4  Latest news: http://r-datatable.com

FruitBought <- fread("name,Date,Qty
Apple,20180101,15
Apple,20180105,20
Banana,20180102,18
Banana,20180109,14")
#order is important before doing cumsum
setorder(FruitBought, name, Date)

fruitSold <- fread("Date,name,sold
20180101,Apple,5
20180102,Apple,3
20180102,Banana,3
20180103,Apple,1
20180103,Banana,4
20180104,Apple,2
20180104,Banana,2
20180105,Apple,1
20180105,Banana,2
20180106,Apple,2
20180106,Banana,3
20180107,Apple,2
20180107,Banana,1
20180108,Apple,0
20180108,Banana,3
20180109,Apple,2
20180109,Banana,1
20180110,Apple,3
20180110,Banana,1")    
#order is important before doing cumsum
setorder(fruitSold, Date, name)
```

Comment: It works.
But i having some difficulties to understand what happen. since i'm not familiar with data.table package. :D
on
`cumsold[
    FruitBought, on=.(name=name, Date>=Date, SoldToDate>CumAvail),
    #for each row in FruitBought, find that first date
    .(Name=i.name, Date=i.Date, Qty, LastSoldOut=x.Date[1L]), by=.EACHI][,
        -(1L:3L)] #remove the joining columns`
is that the syntax for joining.. 
I'll try to understand your code first.
by the way your code is works, and i'd like to say thanks.

Regard,

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the desired output

```
    library(tibble)
    library(tidyverse)

FruitBought <- tribble(
  ~name, ~Date, ~Qty,~id,
  "Apple", 20180101, 15,1,
  "Apple", 20180105, 20,2,
  "Banana", 20180102, 18,1,
  "Banana", 20180109, 14,2,
)

fruitSold <- tribble(
  ~Date,    ~name,  ~sold,~id,
  20180101, 'Apple',    5,1,
  20180102, 'Apple',    3,1,
  20180102, 'Banana',   3,1,
  20180103, 'Apple',    1,1,
  20180103, 'Banana',   4,1,
  20180104, 'Apple',    2,1,
  20180104, 'Banana',   2,1,
  20180105, 'Apple',    1,1,
  20180105, 'Banana',   2,1,
  20180106, 'Apple',    2,1,
  20180106, 'Banana',   3,1,
  20180107, 'Apple',    2,1,
  20180107, 'Banana',   1,1,
  20180108, 'Apple',    0,2,
  20180108, 'Banana',   3,1,
  20180109, 'Apple',    2,2,
  20180109, 'Banana',   1,1,
  20180110, 'Apple',    3,2,
  20180110, 'Banana',   1,1
)

fruitSold$Date <- lubridate::ymd(fruitSold$Date)
FruitBought$Date <- lubridate::ymd(FruitBought$Date )
colnames(fruitSold)

sold <- as.data.frame(fruitSold %>% group_by(name,id) %>% summarise(last_date = max(Date)))

colnames(sold)
colnames(FruitBought)
final <- left_join(FruitBought,sold, by  = c("name","id"))
```